# ERROR : The column index is out of range: 1, number of columns: 0

Tags: postgresql, wso2-data-services-server

I'm using wso2dss 3.0.0.I'm trying to execute a postgresql query i.e.

```
SELECT addressid, geocode
FROM maddress
WHERE geocode::point <@ circle '((18.9750,72.8258), 5)';
```

It is working fine in PostgreSQL.When i'm using same query in wso2dss i.e.

```
SELECT addressid, geocode
FROM maddress
WHERE geocode::point <@ circle '((?,?), ?)';
```

It gives me error like :

```
DS Fault Message: Error in 'SQLQuery.processNormalQuery'
DS Code: DATABASE_ERROR
Source Data Service:-
Name: Geofence_DataService
Location: /Geofence_DataService.dbs
Description: N/A
Default Namespace: http://ws.wso2.org/dataservice
Current Request Name: adding_geofence_op
Current Params: {longitude=72.8258, radius=4, latitude=18.9750}
Nested Exception:-
DS Fault Message: Error in 'createProcessedPreparedStatement'
DS Code: UNKNOWN_ERROR
Nested Exception:-
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: The column index is out of range: 1, number of columns: 0.
```

if i remove `" ' "`(**quotation mark**) of circle then also it will not execute. query '' look like this :

SELECT addressid, geocode
    FROM maddress
    WHERE geocode::point <@ circle ((?,?), ?);

it'll give following error :

```
Caused by: javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamException: DS Fault Message: Error in 'SQLQuery.processNormalQuery'
DS Code: DATABASE_ERROR
Source Data Service:-
Name: Geofence_DataService
Location: /Geofence_DataService.dbs
Description: N/A
Default Namespace: http://ws.wso2.org/dataservice
Current Request Name: geofence_op
Current Params: {longitude=72.8258, radius=4, latitude=18.9750}
Nested Exception:-
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: function circle(record, double precision) does not exist
  Hint: No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type cast
```

But circle is inbuilt geographical function of PostgreSQL then is it necessary to write explicit function? else where is the exact error? Even if i put the query with input parameter as i execute in PostgreSQL then also it's working.If so then why it is not accepting dynamic parameters? Please let me know..

Comment: I don't know wso2dss but the problem appears to be how the parameters are spliced into the string that defines the circle. The second option without the quotes is plain wrong because now PostgreSQL treats `circle ( ... )` as a function for which there is no adequate pattern. Check out how the parameters are put into the query from wso2dss.

Comment: yup..and wso2dss is not able to accept funation..that is the problem

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[Geometric types](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-geometry.html#FUNCTIONS-GEOMETRY-CONV-TABLE) can be input in multiple ways.

- In the first form, your `?` parameters are not replaced with values because they are literal parts of a string. So 0 parameters are expected ...
- In the second form without single quotes, your `?` parameters are replaced, but `((18.9750,72.8258), 5)` is interpreted to be a row type, which doesn't work with `circle()`.

You are trying to invoke the [geometric function `circle()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-geometry.html#FUNCTIONS-GEOMETRY-CONV-TABLE) that takes a `point` and a `double precision` ("center and radius to circle"). These are valid syntax variants:

```
SELECT circle '((18.9750,72.8258), 5)'        AS cast_literal
     ' <(18.9750,72.82580),5>'::circle        AS cast_literal2
     , circle(point '(18.9750,72.8258)', '5') AS literal_point_n_radius
     , circle(point(18.9750,72.8258), '5')    AS point_n_literal_radius
     , circle(point(18.9750,72.8258), 5)      AS point_n_radius
```

[**SQL fiddle.**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/d41d8/4146)
 <sub>The cast to `::text` is just to sanitize the deranged display in SQL fiddle</sub>

In your case, to provide **numeric values** (not a string literal), use the last form and it should work:

```
SELECT addressid, geocode
FROM   maddress
WHERE  geocode::point <@ circle(point(?,?), ?);
```

If wso2dss (which I have no experience with) does not accept functions, you have to use one of the first two forms and provide a ***single*** parameter as string literal:

```
SELECT addressid, geocode
FROM   maddress
WHERE  geocode::point <@ circle ?;
```

... where the parameter is the concatenated literal as displayed above.

You *could* let Postgres do the concatenation and still pass three numeric values:

```
SELECT addressid, geocode
FROM   maddress
WHERE  geocode::point <@ ('(('::text || ? || ',' || ? || '),' || ? || ')')::circle;
```

Comment: @user3129056: Cool. Which of the variants does the job for you?

Comment: SELECT addressid, geocode
FROM   maddress
WHERE  geocode::point <@ circle(point(?,?), ?);  works for me