# error: The column index is out of range: 1, number of columns: 0

Tags: java, postgresql, insert

I'm trying to solve the problem of doing an insert into a Postgresql table

I looked at this similar question but it did not solve my problem

[ERROR : The column index is out of range: 1, number of columns: 0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27480846/error-the-column-index-is-out-of-range-1-number-of-columns-0)

here is the part of code getting the error:

```
String query = "INSERT INTO reviews (nbstar, body, author, product_id) VALUES($1,$2,$3,$4)";

PreparedStatement prepareStatement = connection.prepareStatement(query);
prepareStatement.setInt(1, nbStar);
prepareStatement.setString(2, body);
prepareStatement.setString(3, author);
prepareStatement.setInt(4, productId);

boolean executed = prepareStatement.execute();
```

i tried several times to change the index number but still the same error

and here is the schema of the table:

[table schema](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qSt4V.jpg)

can anyone give me an advice ?

thanks.

Comment: JDBC uses `?` as the parameter placeholder. See the tutorial for details: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/index.html

Comment: also causes same issue if `?` is quoted like '?'` `eg, where ad_date>='?'` is incorrect

Answer (score 25, accepted):

In the sql query, you want to insert the values for 5 fields (id, nbstar, body, author, product_id) but there are only 4 values VALUES($1,$2,$3,$4).

---

Update following your edited question, just modify your query as follows:

```
VALUES($1,$2,$3,$4)
```

to

```
VALUES(?,?,?,?)
```

Comment: The first field is of type serial (auto increment id), i need to insert only the four following values, it means the first one receive the value automatically

Comment: The answer is good when changing VALUES($1,$2,$3,$4) to VALUES(?,?,?,?)

Answer (score 4):

My problem was that the question mark had single quotes around it and I copy pasted the query from straight sql so I just replaced the string with a ?. For example
`Select * from datatable where id = '?'`
and I had to change it to
`Select * from datatable where id = ?`

Comment: I was searching for too long, thanks man!

Answer (score 0):

For me, I had added a comment which included a question mark.
Silly me!

Answer (score 0):

I got that same error because I had the last \n missing in following query, I hope this helps somebody.

```
                    "                order by mp.id desc\n" +
                "                limit 1\n" +
                "            ) as mge_mp\n" +
                "      )\n" +
                "\n" +
                "-- #pageable\n",
```

My last line was

```
                    "-- #pageable",
```

Answer (score 0):

Incase you get this error, for my own issue, I was passing a field ending with a character next to a variable e.g.:

```
select * from my_schema."my_table" mt
where
        mt.field_2 = variable_2
        and mt.field_1 = 'variable_1' 
        [[and cast(mt.date as DATE) = {{date_picked}}]]
```

-> This failed with an error of:
The column index is out of range: 1, number of columns: 0

Changed to:

```
select * from my_schema."my_table" mt
where
        mt.field_1 = 'variable_1' 
        and mt.field_2 = variable_2
        [[and cast(mt.date as DATE) = {{date_picked}}]]
```

- Please note the variable ending with a quote character has been moved.

-> This worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, remove any `sql comments` inside string query.

Answer (score -1):

For me the issue was having a semicolon at the end of the query string. Something like:

```
String query = "INSERT INTO reviews (nbstar, body, author, product_id) VALUES(?,?,?,?);";
```

Notice the `;` appended to the end of the query string. The fix is, well, to remove it:

```
String query = "INSERT INTO reviews (nbstar, body, author, product_id) VALUES(?,?,?,?)";
```